# Issue with mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to create a rule but i'm getting a little confused with mod_rewrite.

I would like to translate the following link:

```
mydomain.com/index.php?page=view&id=100
```

into:

```
mydomain.com/100
```

this is what i've done it as the following but it's not working properly

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=view&id=$1
```

Can you guys help me with it?
thanks for your cooperation

Comment: What URL did you use to test this? Are there more rules?

Comment: And you've got `RewriteEngine On` and mod_rewrite loaded?

Comment: yes 
here the full content of .htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=view&id=$1

Comment: mod_rewrite loaded on apache

Comment: even tried to add the following before the role:
RewriteBase / 
just to make sure... the site is on the root (/home/mycpaneaccount/public_html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php?page=view&id=$1 is incorrect... it's index.php?p=view&id=$1
Now everything is working properly...
Sorry for that